# Use of JComboBoxKeySelectionManager

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to create a mapping between what user enters in JComboBox and the model list, so I tried to use setSelectionKeyManager and override the method selectionForKey without any results, can anyone explain what the real use of SelectionKeyManager ? and how to achieve a working mapping between user input and list model of JComboBox ?

Comment: What's not clear in the javadoc? If you want help, you'd better elaborate on what you want to achieve, show the code that you've tried, explain what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: @JBNizet My real question is : can SelectionKeyManager achieves autocompletion in JComboBox ? (or should i use DocumentListener or AutoCompleteDecorator from swingx)

Comment: AFAIK, no. The SelectionKeyManager is used to select an option from the proposed options, typically in a non-editable combo box.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please give me link to a working example because i want to understand it well, the javadoc is abstract and doesn't explain it well enough.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComboBox.java#JComboBox.DefaultKeySelectionManager

Comment: @JBNizet The example in the link works great, now i understand well how SelectionKeyManager works, thanks really for your great answers.

Answer (score 2):

> The example in the link works great

The example in the link is the default behaviour. It just uses the toString() representation of the Object in the model to do the matching on the key typed by the user. In general the default is fine when you just add String Objects to the ComboBoxModel.

When you start adding other objects and use a custom renderer for the object, then you should consider using a custom KeySelectionManager. See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a general solution that you can use.